# capturing values after an optional slash

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I am trying to write in regex a string that allows me to have

- an alphanumeric string of length no longer than 5 (as an example) [a-z0-9]{3,5}
- followed by an optional forward slash /?
- that cannot end in a 3

I want to capture any group of at least 3, with our without a slash, and then anything after it.

And I am having a very hard time accomplishing this. If I require the slash / it is much easier to do so.

When I try

```
(?=.+\/?.+)[a-z0-9]{2,5}\/?(?<!3\/|3)
```

I can capture what I want - up until the slash, but can't crack how to get anything after IF legit things occur

```
(?=.+\/?.+)[a-z0-9]{2,62}\/?.?
```

My requirement for length goes up by 1 - to 4 instead of 3 - due to the additional `.` I put after the `\/?`. I could change my match to account for it, but it becomes really difficult.

```
(?=.+\/?.+)[a-z0-9]{2,5}\/?(?<!3\/|3)$
```

This only gives me the last slash or non slash follwed by 2,5 characters.

```
(?=.+\/?.+)[a-z0-9]{2,62}\/?.*
```

or

```
(?=.+\/?.+)[a-z0-9]{2,62}\/?.?+
```

simply then ignores my ending rule, of not being able to close with3/ or 3. Also this allows me to use more than 5 characters before the slash. Def not what I want :)

Is there a way to make an optional field still maintain length and ending rules?

I am running this script on both regexr.com and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp and gitbash and not getting the results I would like

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://regex101.com/r/XeNrOt/1

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can capture that no issues - but this aaaa4/w - I want to capture the /w and beyond - and it does not. aaaa3/d - should not capture anything though. so - if the rule before the slash works - i want to capture whats beyond the slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^[a-z0-9]{3,5}(?<!3)(?:$|\/.*)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/U5ELaI/1)

---

`^` - beginning of the string

`[a-z0-9]{3,5}` - capture `a-z0-9` between 3 and 5 times

`(?<!3)` - the last character should not be `3`

`(?:$|\/.*)` - match either end of string `$` or `/` and any number of characters.

Comment: Thank you so much! I even tried capturing groups, but did not think about the or operator there

Answer (score 1):

If the last character in this range `[a-z0-9]` should not be a 3 you can exclude it like `[a-z124-9]`

```
^[a-z0-9]{2,4}[a-z124-9](?:\/.*)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z0-9]{2,4}` Match 2-4 chars in the ranges a-z 0-9
- `[a-z124-9]` Match a single char a-z and then either 1,2 4-9
- `(?:\/.*)?` Optionally match `/` and the rest of the line
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHep44/1).

If you can not match a 3 at all:

```
^[a-z124-9]{3,5}(?:\/.*)?$
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dNMFDK/1)

Comment: Thanks. This will not work exactly like I wanted  - as I cannot use 3 at all. But I can use your idea in this way [a-z0-9.-]{3,5}(?<!3)(?:\/.*)? . Looks like I have more to learn on capturing groups

Comment: @BillPetrosino I see, I have added another pattern that does not match a `3` at all>